# parsing error while uploading file using spring mvc,jquery and ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

i am using spring boot to run my project . I am trying to upload a file. Sometimes I am getting this error

```
java.io.IOException: UT010015: Could not delete file /var/folders/6k/2k84rvv902q2_r1lcmplj2tw0000gn/T/undertow2539812181612076897upload
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.PartImpl.delete(PartImpl.java:111)
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver.cleanupMultipart(StandardServletMultipartResolver.java:86)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.cleanupMultipart(DispatcherServlet.java:1104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:989)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:869)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:86)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:82)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:250)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchToPath(ServletInitialHandler.java:193)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.error(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:403)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.error(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:314)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletResponseImpl.doErrorDispatch(HttpServletResponseImpl.java:148)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:264)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:248)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:167)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:199)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:761)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

And sometimes I am getting a Multipart file parsing error . I will post the error as soon as I find it.

Comment: It would be helpful to provide your ajax request and the controller that handles the file upload.

Comment: @RossiRobinsion I removed the undertow server from my pom.xml . Ian ow getting a new error . I have posted a new question in stack overflow with the controller function and ajax request . Here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33590930/unexpected-eof-read-on-socket-while-uploading-file-using-spring-boot

Comment: I am not sure what's the problem. But can you check this link and see if it works for you: http://hmkcode.com/spring-mvc-upload-file-ajax-jquery-formdata/