# Unexpected EOF read on socket while uploading file using spring boot

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-boot

I am trying to upload a file and I am getting this error just when I click the upload button:-

```
java.io.EOFException: Unexpected EOF read on the socket
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioInputBuffer.fill(InternalNioInputBuffer.java:152)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioInputBuffer$SocketInputBuffer.doRead(InternalNioInputBuffer.java:177)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityInputFilter.doRead(IdentityInputFilter.java:110)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractInputBuffer.doRead(AbstractInputBuffer.java:416)
    at org.apache.coyote.Request.doRead(Request.java:469)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.realReadBytes(InputBuffer.java:342)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.substract(ByteChunk.java:395)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:367)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:190)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.LimitedInputStream.read(LimitedInputStream.java:132)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.makeAvailable(MultipartStream.java:946)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.read(MultipartStream.java:850)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.LimitedInputStream.read(LimitedInputStream.java:132)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:98)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:68)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:293)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2734)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParameters(Request.java:3073)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParameter(Request.java:1095)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParameter(RequestFacade.java:380)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

2015-11-08 12:51:58.964 ERROR 1175 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet dispatcherServlet threw exception

java.io.EOFException: Unexpected EOF read on the socket
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioInputBuffer.fill(InternalNioInputBuffer.java:152)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioInputBuffer$SocketInputBuffer.doRead(InternalNioInputBuffer.java:177)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityInputFilter.doRead(IdentityInputFilter.java:110)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractInputBuffer.doRead(AbstractInputBuffer.java:416)
    at org.apache.coyote.Request.doRead(Request.java:469)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.realReadBytes(InputBuffer.java:342)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.substract(ByteChunk.java:395)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:367)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:190)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.LimitedInputStream.read(LimitedInputStream.java:132)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.makeAvailable(MultipartStream.java:946)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.read(MultipartStream.java:850)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.LimitedInputStream.read(LimitedInputStream.java:132)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:98)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:68)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:293)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2734)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParameters(Request.java:3073)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParameter(Request.java:1095)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParameter(RequestFacade.java:380)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

2015-11-08 12:51:58.969 ERROR 1175 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost]           : Exception Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/error]

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Unexpected EOF read on the socket
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:979)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:869)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:720)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:468)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:391)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:439)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:399)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:180)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Unexpected EOF read on the socket
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.parseRequest(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.<init>(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:78)
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver.resolveMultipart(StandardServletMultipartResolver.java:76)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.checkMultipart(DispatcherServlet.java:1089)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:928)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Unexpected EOF read on the socket
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2807)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParameters(Request.java:3073)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParameter(Request.java:1095)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParameter(RequestFacade.java:380)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    ... 11 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Unexpected EOF read on the socket
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:297)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2734)
    ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Unexpected EOF read on the socket
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioInputBuffer.fill(InternalNioInputBuffer.java:152)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioInputBuffer$SocketInputBuffer.doRead(InternalNioInputBuffer.java:177)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityInputFilter.doRead(IdentityInputFilter.java:110)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractInputBuffer.doRead(AbstractInputBuffer.java:416)
    at org.apache.coyote.Request.doRead(Request.java:469)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.realReadBytes(InputBuffer.java:342)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.substract(ByteChunk.java:395)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:367)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:190)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.LimitedInputStream.read(LimitedInputStream.java:132)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.makeAvailable(MultipartStream.java:946)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.read(MultipartStream.java:850)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.LimitedInputStream.read(LimitedInputStream.java:132)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:98)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:68)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:293)
    ... 27 common frames omitted
```

My ajax code is like this :-

```
$("#upload-files").on("click",function(){

        console.log("upload button clicked");
        var ajaxData = new FormData();
        //var table=$.fn.dataTable.TableTools.fnGetInstance('property-table');
        var srowData=ptable.rows('.selected').data()[0][0];
        //ajaxData.append( 'action','uploadImages');
        ajaxData.append('propertyId',srowData);
        $.each($("input[type=file]"), function(i, obj) {
            $.each(obj.files,function(j,file){
                ajaxData.append('photos['+i+']', file);
            });

         });
        var URL="/fileUpload";
        $.ajax({
            url:URL,
            data: ajaxData,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType:'json',
            success: function(data){
                if(data.status === 'success')
                {
                    location.reload();
                }
           }});
    })

  });
```

Here is the function inside my controller :-

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/fileUpload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public @ResponseBody void fileUpload(@RequestParam(value = "propertyId")Long propertyId,@RequestParam(value = "photos") List<MultipartFile> photos,Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {

      //String response = "generic.unexpectederror";
      try {
          for(MultipartFile file:photos)
          {
              model.addAttribute("message", "File '" + file.getOriginalFilename() + "' uploaded successfully");
              System.out.println("Size of the file is " + file.getSize());
              System.out.println("Name of the file is "  + file.getOriginalFilename());
              //response = "fileUpload.success";
          }

      } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
          //response = "fileUpload.error";
          System.out.println(e);

      }
   }
```

I removed undertow from my POM . When I was using undertow , the error was something like unable to delete some temporary files. I also posted the question in this link [parsing error while uploading file using spring mvc,jquery and ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33585018/parsing-error-while-uploading-file-using-spring-mvc-jquery-and-ajax)

I am also getting this error sometimes while uploading a file :-

```
org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:393)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:426)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:342)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flush(OutputBuffer.java:317)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.flush(CoyoteOutputStream.java:110)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator.flush(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:1022)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:1904)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:231)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:208)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:186)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:146)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:71)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:775)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:869)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:720)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:468)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:391)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:439)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:182)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel.write(NioChannel.java:124)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector.write(NioBlockingSelector.java:101)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.write(NioSelectorPool.java:172)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer.writeToSocket(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:139)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer.addToBB(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:197)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer.access$000(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:41)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer$SocketOutputBuffer.doWrite(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:320)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.ChunkedOutputFilter.doWrite(ChunkedOutputFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractOutputBuffer.doWrite(AbstractOutputBuffer.java:256)
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:388)
    ... 42 common frames omitted
```

On windows even after switching the antivirus off I am getting this error :-

```
org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:393)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:426)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:342)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flush(OutputBuffer.java:317)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.flush(CoyoteOutputStream.java:1
```

I could not post the entire error message due to character limit.